# Why are anonymous edits ever allowed?

Tags: discussion, editing

Every single anonymous edit that I've reviewed has been obvious spam. Is there a good reason to allow anonymous edits, or can we turn this feature off?

Answer (score 2):

Some related reading...

[Prevent suggested edits coming from anonymous users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83457/prevent-suggested-edits-coming-from-anonymous-users)

[Do we have stats showing that anonymous edits are helpful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120849/do-we-have-stats-showing-that-anonymous-edits-are-helpful)

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147295/189958

By the looks of it, when the topic has come up before, the ratio of bad to good is/hasn't been bad enough to axe it.

Comment: Good background commentary. Interesting, no one, not even Jeff Atwood, tries to explain why the feature was introduced in the first place.